# Include libusb in a package without the use of Macports

Tags: macos, usb, macports, packagemaker, libusb

I'm making an installer for my Qt app that communicates with the USB port.
For the app to work, libusb must be installed. I can do that using macports in terminal but that might be a hassle for my users so I'm packaging the app using Apple's package maker tool.
The question is how can I include libusb in a package so that the user won't have to use Macports? Or is there a way I can create a bash script that can install libusb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to compile libusb as static library. So you can link it statically and this way you don't need to ship it separately.